# Need help check the proof for n^5 - n is divisible by 30, prove by method of induction

Tags: linear-algebra, induction

$$(n+1)^5-(n+1)=(n^5-n)+5n^4+10n^3+10n^2+5n=(n^5-n)+5n\left( n^3+2n^2+2n+1 \right)$$
$$=(n^5-n)+5n(n+1)\left( n^2+n+1 \right)$$
$$=(n^5-n)+5n(n+1)\left( (n-1)^2+3n\right)$$ ...1
$$=(n^5-n)+5n(n+1)(n-1)^2+15n^2(n+1)$$

- is divisible by $30$ by the inductive assumption
- $n(n+1)(n-1)$ is the product of three consecutive integers, thus divisible by $2$ and $3$.
- $n(n+1)$ is even.

This answer has been posted before but there was (n-1)^2-3n instead of + 3n.
I have a test in two hours and I just wanted to clear this doubt. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that $n^5 - n = n(n^4 - 1) = n(n^2-1)(n^2 + 1)= n(n-1)(n+1)(n^2 + 1)$

Comment: @amWhy I'm sorry but I didn't follow

Comment: @amWhy could you just check if the proof is correct Please? It would be highly appreciated

Comment: Yes, your proof is OK. The key point in Induction is use one past step to proof the following. $$(n^5-n)+5n(n+1)(n-1)^2+15n^2(n+1)$$

Comment: @RicardoLargaespada thank you very much!